# PDO not reading config correctly

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, propel

I'm not sure what the problem is here, I've inherited some code form Zend Framework and it's using Propel to make DB Queries. I've changed the config file to have the right values in it, username, password, localhost and dbname however, whenever the site has to make a database call it dies with this message:

```
Error processing connection attributes for datasource [pe] [wrapped: Invalid PDO option/attribute name specified: PDO::PROPEL_ATTR_CACHE_PREPARES]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: You should probably add the code that generates the error.

Comment: The error appears whenever the database is queried. I can say, load a login page fine, until I enter the details. It then comes up with this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you specify it as `PDO::PROPEL_ATTR_CACHE_PREPARES`?
It should be `PropelPDO::PROPEL_ATTR_CACHE_PREPARES` or just `PROPEL_ATTR_CACHE_PREPARES`.

Comment: How would I check these? In the /config/propel.php file there is a line that says:

          array (
            'PROPEL_ATTR_CACHE_PREPARES' =>
            array (
              'value' => true,
            ),
          ),

Comment: If I remove the whole attributes key from the propel.php file, it stops displaying that error. It then displays:

Call to undefined method Criteria::hasSelectClause() in /home/richard/application/models/om/BaseDomainPeer.php on line 374